# "Super constructor may only be called once" error with Angular component

Tags: angular

I am getting the following error in Angular `Super constructor may only be called once`.

The component in question very definitely only has `super()` one time, and the line it's breaking on is the first line of the constructor.

[image]

I tried recompiling the app and still get the error on the page in question.

```
polyfills.js:8561 
        
       ERROR ReferenceError: Super constructor may only be called once
    at new DynamicLottiePlayerComponent (pages_home.js:15905:5)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.DynamicLottiePlayerComponent_Factory [as factory] (pages_home.js:16211:10)
    at getNodeInjectable (vendor.js:79689:38)
    at createRootComponent (vendor.js:90176:31)
    at ComponentFactory.create (vendor.js:90030:19)
    at ViewContainerRef.createComponent (vendor.js:100426:43)
    at DynamicComponentPortalHostDirective.attachComponentPortal (vendor.js:61337:34)
    at DynamicComponentPortalHostDirective.attach (vendor.js:60891:19)
    at set portal [as portal] (vendor.js:61302:13)
    at set renderedPageNode [as renderedPageNode] (pages_home.js:28322:23)
```

Comment: Another thing I've noticed about this is that when you add or remove code, your breakpoints will move around. Eventually (inevitably perhaps) a breakpoint will end up on a super() call and suddenly break something that was running just 1 minute before! VERY CONFUSING!

Answer (score 2):

I noticed I had a large number of breakpoints. Deleted all of them and the error went away.

Unfortunately there's no 'undo' for delete breakpoints so I can't diagnose it further right now. I have seen this issue before though.

I'm still not completely clear if this means there is a bug or race condition in Chrome/Edge or if it is in any way Angular related.

Comment: It's strange you not declare the type of the variables in constructor. NOTE: You can use the way: `constructor(private property:any,...){}` to declare and equal the variables at time.

Comment: @Eliseo this is a screenshot from Chrome debugging tools - so any Typescript typing information has already been lost and is impossible to see in Javascript. And yes in the original code they are all strongly typed.

Comment: I saw exactly this in Brave 1.48.164 / Chromium 110... Removal of all breakpoints worked. Thanks!

Comment: @FredG I've had this quite a few times recently. I often end up with a breakpoint on super() due to adding or moving code elsewhere (not deliberately). The breakpoint on super() is what is breaking things for me most often. I haven't had time to report a bug yet.

Comment: @Simon_Weaver Thank you. I was cracking my head to figure out what was going wrong with the code. I removed all breakpoints, and it started working.

Comment: @Joseph It's funny you just got this yesterday because I haven't run across it for a while. There was a period of time where I saw it quite often. Which Angular are you on? I'm on 16.2.0

Comment: @Simon_Weaver, the project I am working on is using Angular version 14.2.10

Answer (score 1):

I want to add to the answer by Simon_Weaver.

I had set a *logpoint* right where `super()` is called inside the constructor.

```
constructor(){
 super(); // logpoint set here.
 ...
}
```

Once I removed that logpoint, I didn't see this above said error.